# Dynamically extract name from variable

Tags: ansible

I have variable with array

```ini
file_name=['test1.zip', 'test2.zip']
```

and I would like to extract the values from the list, so that I get the given value directly and not the whole list. The goal is to create a command to delete the entire path on the server.

For now, I get:

```yaml
/srv/data/['test1.zip', 'test2.zip']
```

but I would like it to be:

```yaml
/srv/data/test1.zip
/srv/data/test2.zip
```

Can I delete files using `rsync`?

Comment: You should look into using [loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-simple-list)!

Comment: [edit] the question and make it [mre]. Otherwise, the question will be closed.

Answer (score 2):

In order to treat elements of a list, you have to use a [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html).
In order to delete file(s), you should not use `rsync`, no, you should use the `file` module, with the [`state: absent`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameter-state).

So your task should be:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "/srv/data/{{ item }}"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ file_name }}"
```